# Sending a MultipartFile to SFTP Outbound adaper as payload

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have to send a MultipartFile which I received through Spring MVC controller to Spring Integration SFTP Outbound adapter channel
The code which I have written is

```
            Message<MultipartFile> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file)
                    .setHeader("customer", customer)
                    .build();
            channel.send(message);
```

Where the file object is of type MultipartFile. Not able to receive the file at sFTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to transform the MultipPartFile to a `byte[]`.

First, use a header enricher to set up the header `FileHeaders.FILENAME` (`file_name`) to the name you want to upload the file as.

Then use a transformer (`expression="payload.bytes"`) to transform the payload to the `byte[]` to send.